# Perlin noise bugged at some devices (Android, glsl)

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am developing OpenGLES app for Android and using Perlin noise from Stefan Gustavson. It's animated 2D noise so I use 3D Perlin with time variable as third dimension. And it was all looking good on my Samsung Galaxy Young (API 10), but when I tested it with ASUS MEMO tablet (API 17) I got this glitchy thing with even elipses and square-like areas:-

[image: this]

What could cause such differences between various devices?

Fragment shader code:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 screenPosition;
uniform vec4 colorFilter;
uniform float time;

vec4 permute(vec4 x)
{
  return mod(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x, 289.0);
}

vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)
{
  return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
}

vec3 fade(vec3 t) {
  return t*t*t*(t*(t*6.0-15.0)+10.0);
}

float noise(vec3 P)
{
  vec3 Pi0 = floor(P); // Integer part for indexing
  vec3 Pi1 = Pi0 + vec3(1.0); // Integer part + 1
  Pi0 = mod(Pi0, 289.0);
  Pi1 = mod(Pi1, 289.0);
  vec3 Pf0 = fract(P); // Fractional part for interpolation
  vec3 Pf1 = Pf0 - vec3(1.0); // Fractional part - 1.0
  vec4 ix = vec4(Pi0.x, Pi1.x, Pi0.x, Pi1.x);
  vec4 iy = vec4(Pi0.yy, Pi1.yy);
  vec4 iz0 = Pi0.zzzz;
  vec4 iz1 = Pi1.zzzz;

  vec4 ixy = permute(permute(ix) + iy);
  vec4 ixy0 = permute(ixy + iz0);
  vec4 ixy1 = permute(ixy + iz1);

  vec4 gx0 = ixy0 / 7.0;
  vec4 gy0 = fract(floor(gx0) / 7.0) - 0.5;
  gx0 = fract(gx0);
  vec4 gz0 = vec4(0.5) - abs(gx0) - abs(gy0);
  vec4 sz0 = step(gz0, vec4(0.0));
  gx0 -= sz0 * (step(0.0, gx0) - 0.5);
  gy0 -= sz0 * (step(0.0, gy0) - 0.5);

  vec4 gx1 = ixy1 / 7.0;
  vec4 gy1 = fract(floor(gx1) / 7.0) - 0.5;
  gx1 = fract(gx1);
  vec4 gz1 = vec4(0.5) - abs(gx1) - abs(gy1);
  vec4 sz1 = step(gz1, vec4(0.0));
  gx1 -= sz1 * (step(0.0, gx1) - 0.5);
  gy1 -= sz1 * (step(0.0, gy1) - 0.5);

  vec3 g000 = vec3(gx0.x,gy0.x,gz0.x);
  vec3 g100 = vec3(gx0.y,gy0.y,gz0.y);
  vec3 g010 = vec3(gx0.z,gy0.z,gz0.z);
  vec3 g110 = vec3(gx0.w,gy0.w,gz0.w);
  vec3 g001 = vec3(gx1.x,gy1.x,gz1.x);
  vec3 g101 = vec3(gx1.y,gy1.y,gz1.y);
  vec3 g011 = vec3(gx1.z,gy1.z,gz1.z);
  vec3 g111 = vec3(gx1.w,gy1.w,gz1.w);

  vec4 norm0 = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(g000, g000), dot(g010, g010), dot(g100, g100), dot(g110, g110)));
  g000 *= norm0.x;
  g010 *= norm0.y;
  g100 *= norm0.z;
  g110 *= norm0.w;
  vec4 norm1 = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(g001, g001), dot(g011, g011), dot(g101, g101), dot(g111, g111)));
  g001 *= norm1.x;
  g011 *= norm1.y;
  g101 *= norm1.z;
  g111 *= norm1.w;

  float n000 = dot(g000, Pf0);
  float n100 = dot(g100, vec3(Pf1.x, Pf0.yz));
  float n010 = dot(g010, vec3(Pf0.x, Pf1.y, Pf0.z));
  float n110 = dot(g110, vec3(Pf1.xy, Pf0.z));
  float n001 = dot(g001, vec3(Pf0.xy, Pf1.z));
  float n101 = dot(g101, vec3(Pf1.x, Pf0.y, Pf1.z));
  float n011 = dot(g011, vec3(Pf0.x, Pf1.yz));
  float n111 = dot(g111, Pf1);

  vec3 fade_xyz = fade(Pf0);
  vec4 n_z = mix(vec4(n000, n100, n010, n110), vec4(n001, n101, n011, n111), fade_xyz.z);
  vec2 n_yz = mix(n_z.xy, n_z.zw, fade_xyz.y);
  float n_xyz = mix(n_yz.x, n_yz.y, fade_xyz.x); 
  return 2.2 * n_xyz;
}

void main() {
    float valuer = (noise(vec3(screenPosition.x*4.0, screenPosition.y*3.0, time)));
    float val1 = 0.25*(sign(valuer+0.2)-sign(valuer-0.2));
    float val2 = 0.125*(sign(valuer+0.4)-sign(valuer-0.4));
    outputColor = colorFilter*(val1+val2+0.25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Samsung Galaxy Young is executing the math at highp, and the ASUS MEMO tablet is executing at mediump.

OpenGLES devices are not required to support highp in fragment shaders, but the above code looks very much like it will be required.

Is that even a full fragment shader? I thought GLES fragment shaders required you to specify a default precision or required you to specify precision on a per-variable basis. I see neither, so perhaps there is some information omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, I omitted first line of shader in my post (edited already).
    precision mediump float;
Without precision specification it's drawing a black polygon.

Comment: Try changing it from "precision mediump float" to "precision highp float". If that fixes the ASUS MEMO tablet, then you've confirmed that the problem is precision. However, if it doesn't fix the problem, then you haven't proven anything, because the Memo tablet might just not support highp in fragment shaders. Also, using highp is not really a fix because your app will only work on some devices and not others, so whatever happens you might need to find a new approach to noise generation that is more tolerant of half-precision.

Comment: Yup, highp fixed glitches but fps dropped significantly. I need another noise generator then. Thanks for your input.